# Excel VBO - Pivot Table Report Layout in Blue Prism

Tags: excel, vba, blueprism

I'm trying to arrange my pivot table's report layout as tabular form.

In the offical document of Microsoft Excel, the related code for changing report layout is:

`pvt.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow`

I wrote this code in Blue Prism as:

`PvtTbl.RowAxisLayout = "xlTabularRow"`

Also tried,

`PvtTbl.RowAxisLayout("xlTabularRow")`

However, somehow I'm facing with the exception. The message is about type mismatch.  xlTabularRow is the child of XlLayoutRow (Source)

Can you please help me?

The whole code:

````
Try

wb = GetWorkbook(Handle, Workbook)
ws = GetWorksheet(Handle, Workbook, Worksheet)

wb.Activate()
ws.Activate()

excel = ws.Application
sheet = excel.ActiveSheet

PvtTbl = ws.PivotTables(PivotTableName)
PvtTbl.RowAxisLayout = "xlTabularRow"

Success = True

Catch e As Exception
Success = False
Message = e.Message()

Finally

PvtTbl = Nothing
ws = Nothing

End Try```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! Just simply change the

`PvtTbl.RowAxisLayout = "xlTabularRow"`

to

`PvtTbl.RowAxisLayout(1)`

Comment: xlTabularRow is a constant value in Excel VBA. You can retrieve the values from the VBA editor in Excel for any of the xl constants using the Immediate window. Entering ?xlTabularRow will give you the value of 1. As a coding practice, I find it helps to define any special values used as a constant in your BluePrism-side code so that future editors will know that, for example, 1 means xlTabularRow.